# Is it possible to add a logo to KivyMD Toolbar?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I'm writitng an app using KivyMD. Is it possible to add a logo to the MDToolbar class? I want the logo to be in the center and have two buttons on its left and right. I tried using the Image and canvas class but it didnt work out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is 2 buttons and a canvas at the center of the toolbar I guess.
This is how you can achieve it.

**Python code**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    
    MDToolbar:
        id: layout
        title: "MDToolbar"
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                source: 'logo.jpg'
                pos: (((self.parent.size[0])/2)-30,self.pos[1])
                size: (60, 60)
        Button:
            text: ''
            pos: (((self.parent.size[0])/2)+60,self.pos[1])
            background_normal: 'right.png'
            background_down: 'right.png'
            size_hint: None, None 
            size: (60, 60)
            on_press: print("right")
            on_release: print("right")
            border: (0,0,0,0)
        Button:
            text: ''
            pos: (((self.parent.size[0])/2)-120,self.pos[1])
            background_normal: 'left.png'
            background_down: 'left.png'
            size_hint: None, None 
            size: (60, 60)
            on_press: print("left")
            on_release: print("left")
            border: (0,0,0,0)
 
    MDLabel:
        text: "Content"
        halign: "center"
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

Window.show_cursor = True

Test().run()
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but now KivyMD has replaced MDToolbar by MDTopAppBar, and your code doesn't work on the last one. Do you know how to manage this same functionality for MDTopAppBar?

Comment: @forvas Try to change the MDToolbar in KV script to MDTopAppBar, It should work.